# Do onClick attribute and click function work on touch screens (smartphones)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, touch

I made a music player plugin using jQuery, HTML5 and SoundCloud. On computers it works perfectly, but on smartphones such as iphone, its does not work the way it must be. For example some buttons work fine, but play button needs to be tapped t 3 times to work. for button in my player I used either on of these example:

```
function play(){
   //play song
}
<div onClick="play()"></div>
```

or

```
$(".playButton").click(function(){
   //playsong
});
<div class="playButton"></div>
```

As some of the buttons and functions need more than one tap to work, I was thinking maybe I must use `.on('tap', function(){});` instead. Or any other feature that works on touchscreens.

So my question is that, for a function to work on smartphones, are the above example fine? Do I need anything else to make sure they work exactly the same as computer version of the plugin?

Comment: Are you using `jQuery Mobile`?

Comment: @Barmar well no, but its my first time I am making a responsive version. Should I use jQuery Mobile too ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with it, but my understanding is that it helps unify the API between desktop and mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using onmousedown instead of onclick.
Or use JQuery to detect tap: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp

Answer (score 0):

"Do I need anything else to make sure they work exactly the same as computer version of the plugin?"

FC: In principle, you do not. `Onclick` works fine on touchscreens; I've used it several times and have never had any problem. It must be something else. Could it be the jQuery that is too heavy for the iPhone? Have you tried it on an iPad, while giving that some time to process the jQuery file(s)?